# Control SVG animation start point

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, css-animations

I have an SVG animation of a `<rect>` that starts at its top left corner.

How can the animation be started at its bottom left corner?

```css
svg {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}

rect {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: #1c7fbf;
  animation: 5s draw linear forwards;
}

@keyframes draw {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 260 260;
    stroke-dashoffset: -260;
    stroke-width: 2px;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 260 260;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    stroke-width: 2px;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox='0 0 90 40'>
  <rect width='90' height='40' />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think, that there's a way to change the starting point, from where a `<rect>`-element is drawn.

However, if you create the rectangle yourself using a `<path>` and [*line commands*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths#Line_commands), and by inverting the start value of `stroke-dashoffset`, you can start in the bottom left or in any other corner you like:

```css
path {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: blue;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-dasharray: 260 260;
  animation: 5s draw linear forwards;
}

@keyframes draw {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 260;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox='0 0 90 40'>
  <path d="M0 40 H 90 V 0 H 0 V 40"/>
</svg>
```

**Demo on jsFiddle**

[Try before buy](https://jsfiddle.net/pbo04Lpk/)

Answer (score 1):

Flipping and repositioning the `<rect>` works:

`transform: scaleY(-1) translateY(-100%);`

also needed to reverse the css animation:

```
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 260 260;
    stroke-dashoffset: 260; // instead of -260
    stroke-width: 2px;
  }
```

```css
svg {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}

rect {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: #1c7fbf;
  animation: 5s draw linear forwards;
  transform: scaleY(-1) translateY(-100%);
}

@keyframes draw {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 260 260;
    stroke-dashoffset: 260;
    stroke-width: 2px;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 260 260;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    stroke-width: 2px;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox='0 0 90 40'>
  <rect width='90' height='40' />
</svg>
```